# Does my motherboard disk controller faulty or somehow?

Tags: 19.04, disk-management, sata

My computer became unstable since a week. First, I changed power supply. After that, I removed offboard video card, but no effect. So yestarday, it couldn't recognize my hard drive anymore.

I did a backup into another disk (Seagate - /dev/sda) and attached to my computer, where I started up a live usb Ubuntu 19.04. Same problems, same issues.

I changed SATA cables but no effect. 
Would my motherboard is faulty? How to determine it? Look at `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Jul  2 03:54:19 ubuntu kernel: [  534.106089] ata3: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
Jul  2 03:54:19 ubuntu kernel: [  534.111029] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/100
Jul  2 03:54:22 ubuntu kernel: [  537.142692] ata3.00: limiting speed to UDMA/66:PIO4
Jul  2 03:54:23 ubuntu kernel: [  538.533689] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 310)
Jul  2 03:54:23 ubuntu kernel: [  539.045598] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 310)
Jul  2 03:54:24 ubuntu kernel: [  539.669548] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 310)
Jul  2 03:54:24 ubuntu kernel: [  539.669562] ata3.00: disabled
Jul  2 03:54:24 ubuntu kernel: [  539.669605] ata3.00: detaching (SCSI 1:0:0:0)
Jul  2 03:54:24 ubuntu kernel: [  539.670387] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Jul  2 03:54:24 ubuntu kernel: [  539.670463] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Jul  2 03:54:24 ubuntu kernel: [  539.670464] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
Jul  2 03:54:24 ubuntu kernel: [  539.670474] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Start/Stop Unit failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Jul  2 03:54:26 ubuntu kernel: [  541.081380] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  2 03:54:26 ubuntu kernel: [  541.869319] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  2 03:54:28 ubuntu kernel: [  543.197234] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  2 03:54:29 ubuntu kernel: [  544.768994] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  2 03:54:30 ubuntu kernel: [  546.020889] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  2 03:54:32 ubuntu kernel: [  547.192770] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  2 03:54:34 ubuntu kernel: [  549.776532] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  2 03:54:39 ubuntu kernel: [  554.148010] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  2 03:54:40 ubuntu kernel: [  555.336006] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  2 03:54:41 ubuntu kernel: [  556.363786] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  2 03:54:42 ubuntu kernel: [  557.587707] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  2 03:54:44 ubuntu kernel: [  559.179482] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  2 03:54:46 ubuntu kernel: [  561.271270] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  2 03:54:47 ubuntu kernel: [  562.595122] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  2 03:54:49 ubuntu kernel: [  564.951089] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  2 03:54:54 ubuntu kernel: [  569.634383] ata3: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
Jul  2 03:54:54 ubuntu kernel: [  569.636432] ata3.00: ATA-8: ST3320418AS, HP35, max UDMA/100
Jul  2 03:54:54 ubuntu kernel: [  569.636436] ata3.00: 625142448 sectors, multi 0: LBA48 NCQ (depth 32)
Jul  2 03:54:54 ubuntu kernel: [  569.637630] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/100
Jul  2 03:54:54 ubuntu kernel: [  569.637901] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      ST3320418AS      HP35 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
Jul  2 03:54:54 ubuntu kernel: [  569.638272] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
Jul  2 03:54:54 ubuntu kernel: [  569.638471] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] 625142448 512-byte logical blocks: (320 GB/298 GiB)
Jul  2 03:54:54 ubuntu kernel: [  569.638508] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
Jul  2 03:54:54 ubuntu kernel: [  569.638513] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
Jul  2 03:54:54 ubuntu kernel: [  569.638574] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
Jul  2 03:54:54 ubuntu kernel: [  569.662634]  sda: sda1
Jul  2 03:54:54 ubuntu kernel: [  569.663234] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
Jul  2 03:55:00 ubuntu kernel: [  575.310210] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  2 03:55:01 ubuntu kernel: [  576.770183] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  2 03:55:05 ubuntu kernel: [  580.946313] ata3: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
Jul  2 03:55:05 ubuntu kernel: [  580.950170] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/100
Jul  2 03:55:09 ubuntu kernel: [  584.886512] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  2 03:55:12 ubuntu kernel: [  587.330555] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  2 03:55:15 ubuntu kernel: [  590.170690] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  2 03:55:15 ubuntu kernel: [  590.170699] ata3.00: disabled
Jul  2 03:55:15 ubuntu kernel: [  590.170726] ata3.00: detaching (SCSI 1:0:0:0)
Jul  2 03:55:15 ubuntu kernel: [  590.171468] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Jul  2 03:55:15 ubuntu kernel: [  590.171525] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Jul  2 03:55:15 ubuntu kernel: [  590.171527] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
Jul  2 03:55:15 ubuntu kernel: [  590.171541] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Start/Stop Unit failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Jul  2 03:55:18 ubuntu kernel: [  593.794782] ata3: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
Jul  2 03:55:18 ubuntu kernel: [  593.797136] ata3.00: ATA-8: ST3320418AS, HP35, max UDMA/100
Jul  2 03:55:18 ubuntu kernel: [  593.797139] ata3.00: 625142448 sectors, multi 0: LBA48 NCQ (depth 32)
Jul  2 03:55:18 ubuntu kernel: [  593.798305] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/100
Jul  2 03:55:18 ubuntu kernel: [  593.798768] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      ST3320418AS      HP35 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
Jul  2 03:55:18 ubuntu kernel: [  593.799213] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
Jul  2 03:55:18 ubuntu kernel: [  593.799302] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] 625142448 512-byte logical blocks: (320 GB/298 GiB)
Jul  2 03:55:18 ubuntu kernel: [  593.799339] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
Jul  2 03:55:18 ubuntu kernel: [  593.799343] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
Jul  2 03:55:18 ubuntu kernel: [  593.799407] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
Jul  2 03:55:18 ubuntu kernel: [  593.826275]  sda: sda1
Jul  2 03:55:18 ubuntu kernel: [  593.827205] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
Jul  2 03:55:20 ubuntu kernel: [  595.850781] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  2 03:55:24 ubuntu kernel: [  599.638908] ata3: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
Jul  2 03:55:24 ubuntu kernel: [  599.641118] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/100
Jul  2 03:55:48 ubuntu kernel: [  623.751095] ata3: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
Jul  2 03:55:48 ubuntu kernel: [  623.753207] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/100
Jul  2 03:55:52 ubuntu kernel: [  627.931107] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  2 03:55:54 ubuntu kernel: [  629.271019] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  2 03:55:55 ubuntu kernel: [  630.675042] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  2 03:55:55 ubuntu kernel: [  630.675052] ata3.00: disabled
Jul  2 03:55:55 ubuntu kernel: [  630.675077] ata3.00: detaching (SCSI 1:0:0:0)
Jul  2 03:55:55 ubuntu kernel: [  630.676096] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Jul  2 03:55:55 ubuntu kernel: [  630.676185] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Jul  2 03:55:55 ubuntu kernel: [  630.676187] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
Jul  2 03:55:55 ubuntu kernel: [  630.676207] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Start/Stop Unit failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Jul  2 03:55:56 ubuntu kernel: [  631.751033] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  2 03:55:58 ubuntu kernel: [  633.507040] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  2 03:56:03 ubuntu kernel: [  638.058988] ata3: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
Jul  2 03:56:03 ubuntu kernel: [  638.059985] ata3.00: ATA-8: ST3320418AS, HP35, max UDMA/100
Jul  2 03:56:03 ubuntu kernel: [  638.059989] ata3.00: 625142448 sectors, multi 0: LBA48 NCQ (depth 32)
Jul  2 03:56:03 ubuntu kernel: [  638.061154] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/100
Jul  2 03:56:03 ubuntu kernel: [  638.061486] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      ST3320418AS      HP35 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
Jul  2 03:56:03 ubuntu kernel: [  638.061998] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
Jul  2 03:56:03 ubuntu kernel: [  638.062154] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] 625142448 512-byte logical blocks: (320 GB/298 GiB)
Jul  2 03:56:03 ubuntu kernel: [  638.062200] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
Jul  2 03:56:03 ubuntu kernel: [  638.062205] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
Jul  2 03:56:03 ubuntu kernel: [  638.062319] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
Jul  2 03:56:03 ubuntu kernel: [  638.082535]  sda: sda1
Jul  2 03:56:03 ubuntu kernel: [  638.083245] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
Jul  2 03:56:06 ubuntu kernel: [  641.494923] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  2 03:56:10 ubuntu kernel: [  645.418825] ata3: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
Jul  2 03:56:10 ubuntu kernel: [  645.420956] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/100
Jul  2 03:56:24 ubuntu kernel: [  659.534520] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  2 03:56:25 ubuntu kernel: [  660.878488] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  2 03:56:30 ubuntu kernel: [  665.126422] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  2 03:56:30 ubuntu kernel: [  665.126428] ata3.00: link offline, clearing class 1 to NONE
Jul  2 03:56:30 ubuntu kernel: [  665.126432] ata3.00: disabled
Jul  2 03:56:30 ubuntu kernel: [  665.126452] ata3.00: detaching (SCSI 1:0:0:0)
Jul  2 03:56:30 ubuntu kernel: [  665.128530] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronizing SCSI cache
Jul  2 03:56:30 ubuntu kernel: [  665.128620] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Synchronize Cache(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Jul  2 03:56:30 ubuntu kernel: [  665.128624] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Stopping disk
Jul  2 03:56:30 ubuntu kernel: [  665.128643] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Start/Stop Unit failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
Jul  2 03:56:34 ubuntu kernel: [  669.378302] ata3: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
Jul  2 03:56:34 ubuntu kernel: [  669.379356] ata3.00: ATA-8: ST3320418AS, HP35, max UDMA/100
Jul  2 03:56:34 ubuntu kernel: [  669.379360] ata3.00: 625142448 sectors, multi 0: LBA48 NCQ (depth 32)
Jul  2 03:56:34 ubuntu kernel: [  669.380574] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/100
Jul  2 03:56:34 ubuntu kernel: [  669.380899] scsi 1:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      ST3320418AS      HP35 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
Jul  2 03:56:34 ubuntu kernel: [  669.381373] sd 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
Jul  2 03:56:34 ubuntu kernel: [  669.381517] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] 625142448 512-byte logical blocks: (320 GB/298 GiB)
Jul  2 03:56:34 ubuntu kernel: [  669.381557] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
Jul  2 03:56:34 ubuntu kernel: [  669.381562] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
Jul  2 03:56:34 ubuntu kernel: [  669.381625] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
Jul  2 03:56:34 ubuntu kernel: [  669.405122]  sda: sda1
Jul  2 03:56:34 ubuntu kernel: [  669.406033] sd 1:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
Jul  2 03:56:38 ubuntu kernel: [  673.398176] ata3: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
Jul  2 03:56:38 ubuntu kernel: [  673.400276] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/100
Jul  2 03:57:17 ubuntu kernel: [  712.276529] ata3: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
Jul  2 03:57:17 ubuntu kernel: [  712.278692] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/100
Jul  2 03:58:45 ubuntu kernel: [  800.038954] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jul  2 03:58:48 ubuntu kernel: [  803.874648] ata3: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
Jul  2 03:58:48 ubuntu kernel: [  803.877529] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/100
Jul  2 03:59:17 ubuntu kernel: [  832.442664] ata3: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
Jul  2 03:59:21 ubuntu kernel: [  836.076128] ata3: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
Jul  2 03:59:21 ubuntu kernel: [  836.078255] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/100
Jul  2 03:59:30 ubuntu kernel: [  845.307380] ata3: SATA link up 1.5 Gbps (SStatus 113 SControl 310)
Jul  2 03:59:30 ubuntu kernel: [  845.309606] ata3.00: configured for UDMA/100
```

Look that my system tries to connect at 1.5 Gbps and 3.0 Gbps, UDMA/100 and UDMA/66 alternately.

Weird! I have another disk (SAMSUNG - /dev/sdb) stable at all. Look at `lshw -C disk`:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lshw -C disk
  *-disk                    
       descrição: SCSI Disk
       produto: Flash Disk
       fabricante: Generic
       ID físico: 0.0.0
       informações do barramento: scsi@6:0.0.0
       nome lógico: /dev/sdc
       nome lógico: /cdrom
       versão: 8.07
       serial: A
       tamanho: 14GiB (15GB)
       capacidades: removable
       configuração: ansiversion=4 logicalsectorsize=512 mount.fstype=iso9660 mount.options=ro,noatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048 sectorsize=512 state=mounted
     *-medium
          ID físico: 0
          nome lógico: /dev/sdc
          nome lógico: /cdrom
          tamanho: 14GiB (15GB)
          capacidades: partitioned partitioned:dos
          configuração: mount.fstype=iso9660 mount.options=ro,noatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048 signature=46f8e7bf state=mounted
  *-disk
       descrição: ATA Disk
       produto: ST3320418AS
       fabricante: Seagate
       ID físico: 0.0.0
       informações do barramento: scsi@1:0.0.0
       nome lógico: /dev/sda
       versão: HP35
       serial: 9VML55HS
       tamanho: 298GiB (320GB)
       capacidades: partitioned partitioned:dos
       configuração: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 signature=ed9b4215
  *-disk
       descrição: ATA Disk
       produto: SAMSUNG HD502HI
       ID físico: 0.0.0
       informações do barramento: scsi@3:0.0.0
       nome lógico: /dev/sdb
       versão: 1118
       serial: S1ZVJ50S605672
       tamanho: 465GiB (500GB)
       capacidades: partitioned partitioned:dos
       configuração: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 signature=00070686
```

`fdisk -l`

```
sudo fdisk -l
Disco /dev/sdb: 465,8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 setores
Disk model: SAMSUNG HD502HI 
Unidades: setor de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Tamanho de setor (lógico/físico): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Tamanho E/S (mínimo/ótimo): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Tipo de rótulo do disco: dos
Identificador do disco: 0x00070686

Dispositivo Inicializar    Início       Fim   Setores Tamanho Id Tipo
/dev/sdb1   *                2048 368642047 368640000  175,8G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb2               737282048 976773119 239491072  114,2G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb3               368642048 733186047 364544000  173,8G 83 Linux
/dev/sdb4               733186048 737282047   4096000      2G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Partições lógicas fora da ordem do disco.


Disco /dev/sdc: 14,5 GiB, 15581839360 bytes, 30433280 setores
Disk model: Flash Disk      
Unidades: setor de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Tamanho de setor (lógico/físico): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Tamanho E/S (mínimo/ótimo): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Tipo de rótulo do disco: dos
Identificador do disco: 0x46f8e7bf

Dispositivo Inicializar  Início     Fim Setores Tamanho Id Tipo
/dev/sdc1   *                 0 4095999 4096000      2G  0 Vazia
/dev/sdc2               4066772 4074259    7488    3,7M ef EFI (FAT-12/16/32)


Disco /dev/sda: 298,1 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 setores
Disk model: ST3320418AS     
Unidades: setor de 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Tamanho de setor (lógico/físico): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Tamanho E/S (mínimo/ótimo): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Tipo de rótulo do disco: dos
Identificador do disco: 0xed9b4215

Dispositivo Inicializar Início       Fim   Setores Tamanho Id Tipo
/dev/sda1                 2048 625141759 625139712  298,1G 83 Linux
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved... Just my fault. I buy a newer power supply, and it's not bivolt. As the voltage from my house is 125v and it comes 220v factory settled, I forgot to switch it to 125v, causing lower voltage!...